# What is the diffusivity of colloidal Formazine in water?

Tags: physical-chemistry, polymers, optical-properties, statistical-mechanics

I have synthesized Foramzine in an aqueous solution (turbidity = 4000 NTU), and will be further diluting it. I would like to know the diffusion coefficient (diffusivity/mass diffusivity) of colloidal Formazine in water. Is there existing literature where I could find the information?

Comment: A lot of the basic work on reactions and diffusion was done using colloids so there should be lots in the literature. In the meantime you could use the Stokes-Einstein eqn. if you know the radius $\displaystyle D=k_BT/(6\pi\eta r)$ where $K_B$ is the Boltzmann constant, $\eta$ the solvent viscosity (Pa s).